# Uninstall Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, developer-tools

I installed Xcode 4.5 DP1 when it was released to developers. However, now that Xcode 4.5 was released in the Mac App Store, I no longer need the DP1. How can I completely remove it (and the new versions of the dev tools that it installed, if any) without affecting my regular Xcode installation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete the old application from your Applications folder. Xcode installations are self contained and can have multiple installs on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks - however, I think I've installed the Command Line tools for Xcode 4.5 DP1 as well. How would I uninstall those?

Comment: Nothing, they are all installed in Xcode.app. (If you show the package contents of Xcode, the command line tools are in there as well).